# Javascript queue a function after another completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long running function A(). And my function B(){} can be called anytime.

Note function B doesn't have to be called after A. But if it is called and if A is running, then A must be finished. And then run B.

I thought about promise.then(), but B may not necessarily be called after A. So it is not much useful in this situation.

How to 'queue' B to ensure the logic?

Comment: What makes you think that B will start executing before A finishes? What is your environment? You may want to read something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734025/is-javascript-guaranteed-to-be-single-threaded

Comment: are A and B synchronous or asynchronous? If they are both synchronous you don't need to do anything, A will halt the execution of B until it's finished.

Comment: Both A and B is async.

Comment: Set a flag. Call A. Use a .then. If the flag is set, place B in a queue array, else call B. In the .then clear the flag, then call any functions in the queue array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use flags! They are completely unnecessary.

Also don't do anything special in `A()` or `B()`. Just write them as you would normally to perform their duties.

Just implement a queue in the form of a dynamically updated promise chain.

```
var q_ = Promise.resolve();

function queue(fn) {
    q_ = q_.then(fn);
    return q_;
}
```

Now you can queue `A` and `B`, or any other function, as follows :

```
queue(A);
queue(B);
queue(someOtherFunction);
```

Or, if you need to pass parameters :

```
queue(A.bind(null, 'a', 'b', 'c'));
queue(B.bind(null, 'x', 'y', 'z'));
queue(someOtherFunction.bind(null, 1, 2, 3));
```

As a bonus,

- `A()` and `B()` (and other functions) remain available to be called directly (unqueued).
- you needn't worry whether functions passed to `queue()` are synchronous or asynchronous. It will work with either.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6ynd08j7/)**

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:
Define a variable `var inQueue = 0`;
When A starts, set a variable `inQueue = 1`, when it finishes, set it to `inQueue = 0`. Now place a check like

```
if(!inQueue) B();
```

This will ensure B won't interrupt A.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable that is `true` when `A` is running and is set to `false` at the end of `A`.  Check that within `B`.  If it is running, have it wait a second and call `B` again.

```
var isARunning

A() {
  isARunning = true
  //do the things
  isARunning = false
}

B() {
  if (isARunning) {
   setTimeout(() => { B() }, 1000);
  }
  else {
    // do more things
  }
}
```